# Trouble populating a ListView using Firebase

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I can't populate a ListView using Firebase.

There is no error that comes but the data that is stored in Firebase (Data is being stored onto firebase-- I can see it) is not at all populating the ListView.
I have tried the commented part too.

Here is most of my code I think that will be relevant:

```
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
    import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
    import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
    import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

public class socialpage2 extends ListActivity {
private ChatListAdapter mChatListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_socialpage2);
   // GlobalClass g=(GlobalClass)getApplicationContext();
   // ListView messageList=g;

     final String user=getIntent().getExtras().get("UserName").toString();
    final String[] message = new String[1];
    Button sendBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    final EditText txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    final ListView messageList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    final Firebase ref=new Firebase("https://---.firebaseio.com/");


    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            message[0] = txt.getText().toString();
            ChatMessage chat=new ChatMessage(user, message[0]);
               ref.push().setValue(chat);
                txt.setText("");

        }
    });
    /*ListAdapter mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(ref, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.chat_item_rcv, this) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage ChatMessage) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lbl3)).setText(ChatMessage.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lbl1)).setText(ChatMessage.getMessage());
        }
    };
    if(messageList!=null) {
        messageList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
        //g.setContent(messageList);
        setContentView(messageList);
        }*/

    // Tell our list adapter that we only want 50 messages at a time
   /* mChatListAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(ref, this, R.layout.chat_item_rcv);
    if(messageList!=null) {
        //messageList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
        //g.setContent(messageList);
        messageList.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);
        setContentView(messageList);
    }*/
   // messageList.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);

    final List<ChatMessage> messages=new LinkedList<>();
    final ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage>(
            this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,messages
    ){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if(view==null)
            {
                view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, parent, false);
            }
            ChatMessage chat=messages.get(position);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lbl3)).setText(chat.getName());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lbl1)).setText(chat.getMessage());


            return view;
        }
    };
    if(messageList!=null)
    {
        messageList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    ref.addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ChatMessage chat=dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
            messages.add(chat);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
 }
}
```

Here is my code : ChatMessage:

```
public class ChatMessage {

private String name,message;
public ChatMessage(){

}
public ChatMessage(String name, String message)
{
      this.name=name;
    this.message=message;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
 }
}
```

Here is my XML for socialpage2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/chat_item_rcv" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        style="@style/edittext_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Type Here" >


    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        style="@style/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_send" />

       </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my XML code for chat_item_rcv:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llaa"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pad_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_gray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pad_5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_chat_item"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14sp" 
            android:maxLines="4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_14sp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_20dp"
        />
```

Here is what I get on my Android Monitor whenever I fill Firebase:
[image: Android Monitor]

Comment: it seems u re using legacy code. refer to new firebase doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake:
I was calling the wrong ListView.

```
*final ListView messageList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);*
```

but this should have been this:

```
**ListView messageList=getListView();**
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check that you are able push your data in `firebase` properly and use below instant to push/get data as define here.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

```
//Database instance ref. to push and get data
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Now, After successfully push data, try to retrieve data like this..

```
List<yourModel> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        // Here yourModel/Data class
        yourModel mChat= eventSnapshot.getValue(yourModel.class);


        Log.e("NAME " ,""+ mChat.getName());   
        Log.e("MESSAGE " ,""+ mChat.getMessage());  

        //Add Data to d List
        mDataList.add(mChat); 
    }
}
```

And then use this `messages`List to show data in your List

Comment: :I am sorry but I am kind of a beginner so I know this question might sound stupid but I was wondering what did you mean by:

 "First of all check that you are able push your data in firebase properly and use below instant to push/get data as define here.."

I went to the website but I really couldn't understand it entirely. So I was wondering whether you could give me some examples and also a brief explanation (I don't want to waste your time) on how it works and how to go about it.

That would be very appreciated-I am a beginner, so I am sorry for the question.
Thanks

Comment: Check your firebase web console, whether data which you want to display is available there or not. If it's there on firebase server then create database instance as shown above to fetch data and use it accordingly, I believe it's clear to you. Thanks.

Comment: I got this error-- I copied exactly what you gave me

Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.example.///.firebaselearn.ChatMessage] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method

Comment: The Error is coming at :ChatMessage mChat= eventSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);

Comment: I took away the for loop and the error went away. I then noticed the "Log" and I saw that the program was able to receive data from firebase but populating the listview with the data is the problem now.

Comment: That ChatMessage.class is your model class have you created ?? If it's not there then it will give u error, and use the same model class during pushing data and fetching

Comment: I do have the class and I am able to get the values I want from firebase but I am not sure how to populate the listview with them. The Log.e gave showed values that were there in firebase:
**09-19 20:18:22.214 ////com.example.///.firebaselearn E/NAME: harsha** and 
**09-19 20:18:22.214 ////com.example.///.firebaselearn E/MESSAGE: Hi**

Comment: do as i suggested in answer just add this values in list.. see my updated answer

Comment: how do I use mDataList to put everything into my ListView?
I am sorry this might be a dumb question.